# html hidden scrollbar in global, how can i display it inside a div tag

Tags: html, css

If i remove the global scrollbar setting, is display.

```
<body>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>

body {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none
  }
}

.content {
  height: 10px
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I tried this, but not scrollbar alway disappear;

```
.content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none
}
```

Comment: so you want a scrollbar in a div?

Comment: Just as a side note: hiding the scroll bar using `::-webkit-scrollbar` won't work on all browsers. Some browsers will still display the scrollbar regardless of what you set. You also don't have valid CSS syntax.

Comment: yep, specific div, and hidden others div scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
body {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none
  }
}

.content {
  height: 10px
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to

```
.content {
  height: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and you forgot `;` in your height..
Here is a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zyap6no/).

Comment: Oh, i forgot it when typing, but global setting hidden is needed for other div, is too many, [Concerned] , so i want display it in specific div. but i don't know how to recover it.

Comment: look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7zyap6no/1/).. do you want to remove scrollbar at the side?

Comment: yes, and only retain first one scrollbar, so setting global hidden.

Comment: yes, but body still need scroll with out scrollbar, strange demand, ha...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, change the setting for global scrollbar

change this:

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
```

to

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
  }
```

and if somewhere i need it:

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ddd;
  }
```

yep, it's worked, maybe { width: auto } match better.